# Warning: getimagesize(upload/18.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php, getimagesize

the error is on line 27 "getimagesize" function ,  I upload the image in the same "path" , but when i proceed with the actions , i got this error everytime , and the path to the folder where the image  is okay

php
    //connect to the database

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost" , "333" , "3333")
    or die( "could not connect " . mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db("moviesite" , $link)
    or die ( mysql_error() );

// make variables available
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
if (isset($_REQUEST['mode']))
{
    $move = $_REQUEST['mode'];
}
else
{
    $mode = '' ;
}

    // get info on the pic we want
$getpic = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = '$id' ")
            or die( mysql_error() ) ;
        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($getpic);
        extract($rows);
    $image_filename = "upload/" . $image_id . ".jpg" ;

    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image_filename);
```

?

Comment: can you please add getimagesize function?

Comment: Check file permissions, it may not be accessible to all. Try setting it to 755 or 777

Answer (score 0):

try to check first if the file exists:

```
if (!file_exists($image_filename)){
    echo "file not found!";
    exit;
}
```